# Is ZeroMQ slower than boost asio?

Tags: performance, zeromq

I am trying to write a network transfer application.

The data is binary data and each packet size is mostly 800KB.

The client produces 1000 data per second. I want transfer data as quick as possible.

When I use ZeroMQ, the speed hits 350 data per second, but the boost asio hits 400(or more) per second.

As you can see the performance of both methods is not good.

The pattern used for ZeroMQ is a **`PUSH/PULL`** pattern, the boost asio is simple sync I/O.

**Q1:** I want to ask, is ZeroMQ only suitable for small messages?

**Q2:** Is there a way to  improve the ZeroMQ speed?

**Q3:** If ZeroMQ can't, please advice some good method or library to improve these kind of data transfer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Data Rate**

You're attempting to move 800 MByte/second. What sort of connection is this? For a `tcp://` transport-class it'd have to something pretty rapid, e.g. 100 Gbit/s Ethernet, which is pretty exotic.

So I'm presuming that it's an **`ipc://`** transport-class connection. In which case you can get an improvement, using ZeroMQ zerocopy functions, which saves copying the data repeatedly.

With a normal transfer, you have to copy data into a zmq message, that has to be copied into an `ipc` pipe, copied out again, and copied back into a new zmq message at the receiving end. All that copying requires 4 x 800 = 2.4 GByte/sec memory bandwidth which, by the time cache conflicts have come into play, is an appreciable percentage of the total memory bandwidth of a typical PC system. Using zerocopy ***should*** cut that in half.

**Alternative to Zero Copy - Zero Transfer**

If you are using `ipc://`, then consider not sending data through the sockets, but sending references to the data through the sockets.

I have previously blended use of zmq and a semaphore locked C++ **`stl::queue`**, using zmq simply for it's pattern ( `PUSH/PULL` in my case ), the `stl::queue` to carry shared pointers to data, and leave the data still. The sender locks the queue, puts a shared pointer into it, and then sends a simple message ( e.g. "1" ) through a zmq socket. The recipient reads the "1" and uses that as a cue to lock the queue and pull a shared pointer off it. Thus a shared pointer to data has been transferred from one thread to another in a ZMQ pattern via a `stl::queue`, but the data itself has stayed still. All I've done is pass ownership of the data between threads. It works so long as the shared pointer that the send has goes out of scope immediately after sending and is not used by the sender to modify or access the data.

`PUSH/PULL` is not too bad to deal with - each message goes to only one recipient. It would take more effort to make such a blend with `PUB/SUB`, and received messages would have to be treated as read-only because each recipient would have a shared pointer to the same block of data as everyone else.

**Message Size**

I've not idea how big a chunk zmqtp transfers at a time, but I'd guess that it's relatively efficient in terms of protocol:data ratio.